How to do Nikkah when your parents are oppising your marriage?
Assalamu Alaikum , I am a software engineer of age 25. I earn a good amount of money Alhamdullilah. I want to do Nikkah as Islam orders us to do so to protect your iman.
I have 2 unmarried elder brothers and my parents says you can't marry before them as its against our cultural norms etc etc.
I am trying to find a spouse on my own but no father gives his daughter to a man who is marrying without his parents approval.
I am falling into sin and I dont know where to find a good spouse. I tried everything convincing my parents to arrange my nikkah but they are stubborn.

We are not a peer support group. You can try to convince your parents using other strategies such as having a scholar to talk to them. You can also marry against their wishes. If you look hard enough you will find people who will agree to give their daughter in marriage to you. You can even consider marrying an orphan or someone who is poorer than you etc.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that Islam doesn't require the parent's consent for marriage for a male, this might be a cultural matter only, also an order for marriage for the children has no backup in Allah's shari'a. So as is written your question has some elements of an advice-request which is hardly on-topic on the site. I'd suggest you to rephrase your inquiry to make it fit more see [ask].
